# Class name must be a valid object or a string - filamentphp form action

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

Getting this error when setting a label for the Create button on the form

`Class name must be a valid object or a string`

Here is my code that produces the error

```
protected function getCreateFormAction(): Action
{
    return CreateAction::make()->label("Create My label");
}
```

Using the default works, but i want to change the label of the create button in the form.

Following code works but it makes a submit button on the form with text `Create` that is default.

```
protected function getCreateFormAction(): Action
{
    return CreateAction::make();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change go to for example you have CategoryResource :

CategoryResource/Pages/ListCategories

```
protected function getActions(): array
{
    return [
        Actions\CreateAction::make()->label('Create My label'),
    ];
}
```